# Example from "Sams teach yourself C" Uses "fgets" but returns errors

Tags: c++, c, compilation, fgets

The code included is exactly out of the book example, but it returns errors. Is there something that the book has done incorrectly? I've never used `#include <string.h>` before, only `#include <stdio.h>`, but still I'm at a loss of what the three arguments are supposed to be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[256];

    printf("Enter your name and press <Enter>:\n");
    fgets(buffer);

     printf("\nYour name has %d characters and spaces!",
         strlen(buffer));
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler says

```
Semantic issue with (fgets( buffer ); - Too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 1

Format string issue (strlen(buffer)); - Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long'
```

Comment: "I've never used #include before, only #include..." Errhh... What?!?

Comment: Posting the code would probably be helpful, but `fgets` parameters are 1. The string buffer to write to, 2. The maximum number of characters to write (usually the size of the buffer), and 3. A `File*` to the stream being read from.  More can be found here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets

Comment: Code is required to help. We don't necessarily own the book, and even if we did, there is a very good possibility that we don't know which example you're talking about. Anytime you ask a question here, you should post some code demonstrating the problem, and try your best to explain what it is supposed to do as well as what it actually does.

Comment: Sorry about that, I got distracted and didn't post the code.

Comment: Again, sorry...also forgot to post the errors.

Comment: @Gideon ,don't forget to upvote and mark an answer as accepted if they helped you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fgets()` must take three parameters.

1. The string were to put the read value
2. The number of bytes to write in this string. But if you the *`Enter key caracter`* is found it will stop at this moment.
3. The stream where to read the data from.

Here you are only specifying one argument so this is not enough. This is what causes the error. There is a *`simplified`* version of fgets that just reads data that is typed by the user and it is called `gets()`.

```
gets(buffer);
```

But this function is unsafe because if the user inputs more bytes than the size of your buffer then you will have a memory overflow. That is why you should use `fgets()`.

Like this:

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
```

Note that I have passed the values `sizeof buffer` and `stdin`. `sizeof buffer` is to ensure we don't get a memory overflow. `stdin`is the stream that *corresponds* to the keyboard. So then we read safely data from the keyboard and you will have a working code.

See references here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

And also if you are interested there are other functions to read user inputs, such as `scanf()`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf

Comment: +1 for such a thorough explanation. Always use `fgets`, or `gets_s`, or something of that nature -- the primary reason being to avoid buffer overflows. It is worth noting that the original `gets` function has been completely removed from the 2011 ISO C standard. While it may work for some time, I would expect it to disappear in a decade or two, assuming people stop writing books that use it or even reference it...

Comment: `s/250/sizeof buffer`. Always prefer delegating computations to the compiler instead of hard-wiring constants in your code.

Answer (score 5):

The correct format to fgets is:

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

So in your case it should be like this:
`fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);`

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the documentation regarding fgets?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

There is also an example of its appropriate use.

This is outdated code because gets() is deprecated, but to get your example working you can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[256];

    printf("Enter your name and press <Enter>:");
    gets(buffer);

    printf("\nYour name has %d characters and spaces!\n", (int)strlen(buffer));

    return 0;
}
```

Have fun!